# How do I press keyboard with robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, visual-studio-code, robotframework

I am trying to implement an automation project by using a **Robot Framework** based on Python. In my case, I need to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, I have used [ASCII Table](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Ewatson/scen103/ascii.html), `selenium.webdriver.common.keys` ([docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html)), but it still doesn't work, the detail is below:

---

### Environment

**OS:** Mac 10.15.7
**Code editor:** Visual Studio Code

---

### Code

```
***setting***
Library   OperatingSystem
Library   DateTime
Library   OperatingSystem
Library   RequestsLibrary
Library   BuiltIn
Library   Collections
Library   json
Library   Selenium2Library
Resource  ./resource1.robot

*** Variables ***
${collection_name}    //input[@name='name']

***Test case***
press keys   ${collection_name}  \\1
```

---

### Actual result

Key "\1" in the locator

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZaZD.png)

---

### Expected result

Select all in the locator

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmUG2.png)

---

Is there any solution to the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Input%20Text

Comment: What are you trying to do with the selected text from that input?

Comment: I want to selected the text, then delete it.

Comment: I want to clear the text

Comment: my issue is similar to this 
https://forum.robotframework.org/t/for-input-clear-on-robotframework-how-to-do-best/648

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things wrong in your script so to start with those issues first.

### Test case is not a keyword

Your tests must be structured so that there is at least one keyword inside the test case - Currently you are having a test case which has a name
`press keys   //input[@name='name']  \\1`.

For correct test case structure, please refer to [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-suites) - Adding a test case, and using keyword inside the test case will work fine.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Pressing Keys
    Press Keys    ${collection_name}    \\1
```

### Selenium2Library doesn't have keyword `Press Keys`

It would be recommended to change to using `SeleniumLibrary` instead of `Selenium2Library`. Unless of course the choise was made for a reason, in which case reading through the keyword documentation would help you a lot here.

Consider comparing the keywords available for [Selenium2Library](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Text) and [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys). Notice that the `SeleniumLibrary` no longer seems to support ASCII keycodes. With `SeleniumLibrary` following should work fine.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Pressing Keys
    Press Keys    ${collection_name}    CTRL+A
```

In `Selenium2Library` It would look like following

```
*** Test Cases ***
Pressing Keys
    Press Key    ${collection_name}    \\1
```

### Opinion: Replying to the comments under the question

From the comments I understood that the end goal was to simply clear the text from an edit field. Following the exact user inputs with keyboard would be unnecessary and unless for a specific reason (some event trigger for example) this is not recommended. Instead reducing the amount of inputs required makes the script easier to read and maintain in the long run.

Consider using keyword `Clear Element Text` from either `SeleniumLibrary` or `Selenium2Library` or `Input Text` from `SeleniumLibrary` to either clear the field or to clear the field and then input your own text. For additionally capturing the existing text, use `Get Text` keyword from either of the libraries.

As an example following test case would get text, clear the text and then check that the element is empty. It should work with both of the libraries.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Pressing Keys
    ${text}=    Get Element Text    ${collection_name}
    Clear Element Text    ${collection_name}
    Element Text Should Be    ${collection_name}    ${EMPTY}
```

Comment: To clarify, SeleniumLibrary does not support ASCII codes. The old Selenium2Library keyword ``Press Key`` did, but unless you have an already existing large test suite made with the old library using it isn't recommended.

Comment: thanks! but I try the method which you provide , it still not work .

press keys   ${collection_name}  CTRL+A

Comment: Which version of Robot and Python are you running? I just noticed that you actually are importing the old Selenium2Library - It might be good idea to try and use SeleniumLibrary instead.

Comment: Also adjusted my response to your comments on the question.

Comment: 1. I  adjust the library to SeleniumLibrary , but still not work.

2. python version is 3.9.4

3. robot robotframework in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.0.1)

Comment: Is there some error you are getting? If you use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, do you have the SeleniumLibrary mentioned in the installed packages?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! finally , I use this way to solve this issue : 

Repeat keyword  ${10}  press keys   ${collection_name}  BACKSPACE+BACKSPACE+BACKSPACE+BACKSPACE+BACKSPACE
input text  ${collection_name}  edittest